# How to differentiate the multivariable equation properly?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

The temperature of hot surface is given by
$$
T=100e^{−(x^2+y^2)}
$$
A bug follows the trajectory $r(t) = [t \cos(2t), t\sin(2t)]$.

$$
\frac {\partial x}{\partial t}=\cos(2t)-2t\sin(2t), \quad \frac {\partial y}{\partial t}=\sin(2t)+2t\cos(2t) \tag2
$$

How to obtain these answer from the differentiation of dy/dt and dx/dt using the Chain Rule?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Two approaches. I've tried to plug in these values into functions and then differentiate, but then I am completely stuck. Then I've tried to differenatiate a function and then differentiate vector-values, but here I am stuck even more. So I need someone to guide me through with that

Comment: @MariaLavrovskaya Why is $T$ introduced? Do you want to differentiate that, too?

Comment: The question was to find dT/dt, but since I figured out the first part, I couldn't understand how I can go with dx/dt and dy/dt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are saying that $r$ is a path in the $xy$-plane that varies with $t$. So, you can write $r(t)=(x(t),y(t)).$ Since we also know that $r(t)=(t\cos 2t, t\sin 2t),$ it follows that $x(t)=t\cos 2t,$ and similarly for $y$. Hence, $$\frac{d}{dt} x(t)=\frac{d}{dt}(t\cos 2t)=\cos 2t-2t\sin 2t,$$ just using the product and chain rule from one-variable calculus. Finding $\frac{dy}{dt}$ is similar.

Comment: In this case is it $\frac{dR}{dt}$ as a function of X?

Comment: Based on the context, they are saying that $r(t)$ traces out a path in the $xy$-plane, with the coordinates changing in $t$.

Comment: So then we get dx/dt?

Comment: Since we know that $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ and $r(t)=(t\cos 2t, t\sin 2t),$ we know that $x(t)=t\cos 2t$ and $y(t)=t\sin 2t.$ Now, we can just take derivatives.